# How to set MSDeploy settings in .csproj file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, msdeploy

Is there a way to set MSDeploy parameters in .csproj file itself of ASP.NET MVC project? Particularly a "skip" parameter, which should skip a "Temp" folder.

```
-skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="\\temp"
```

.. or how can I pass this parameter into MSBuild.exe arguments list?

Comment: How your target is defined? You running msbuild.exe explicitly?

Comment: MSBuild.exe is executed by TFS Build server with arguments similar to this: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish;MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC;MsDeployServiceUrl=...`

Comment: Can you add an argument explicitly like msbuild.exe /p:absolutePath="\\temp" ?

Comment: I don't think so, since absolutePath is a value of -skip parameter which should be passed to msdeploy.exe

Comment: When I try this, I get "Unrecognized skip directive 'skipaction'." in the build.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Define `<MsDeploySkipRules>` in the project file. For example:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OnBeforePackageUsingManifest>AddSkipRules</OnBeforePackageUsingManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="AddSkipRules">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipTempDirOnDeploy">
        <SkipAction></SkipAction>
        <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>$(_Escaped_PackageTempDir)\\Temp$</AbsolutePath>
        <XPath></XPath>
      </MsDeploySkipRules>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: For it to work during deployment through Visual Studio "Publish" feature one have to use `AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest` instead of `OnBeforePackageUsingManifest`. See comment http://blog.alanta.nl/2011/02/web-deploy-customizing-deployment.html?showComment=1314013105475#c1406362862563428999

Comment: When I try this, I get "Unrecognized skip directive 'skipaction'." in the build. What am I missing?

Comment: I think it should be "<SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>"

Comment: I tried "<SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>" but it also didn't work. I had to completely remove the SkipAction element. Also, thanks Anthony Serdyukov for your comment. It was very useful.