# Skip rule is not working

Tags: .net, msbuild, msdeploy

I've edited my csproj file according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5659390/1003222), but the extra files in App_data will be deleted anyway. 
On the other hand, when I modify the msdeploy command as shown in the post, the skip is applied.

I'm using web deploy v3. And the command is

```
msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package=c:\builds\app.zip -dest:auto -setParam:"IIS Web Application Name"="Default Web Site/app"
```

Is there anyway to debug what can be causing this behavior ?

```
  <PropertyGroup>    <OnBeforePackageUsingManifest>AddCustomSkipRules</OnBeforePackageUsingManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="AddCustomSkipRules">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipDeleteAppData">
        <SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>
        <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>$(_Escaped_PackageTempDir)\\App_Data\\.*</AbsolutePath>
        <XPath>
        </XPath>
      </MsDeploySkipRules>
      <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipDeleteAppData">
        <SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>
        <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>$(_Escaped_PackageTempDir)\\App_Data\\.*</AbsolutePath>
        <XPath>
        </XPath>
      </MsDeploySkipRules>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been reviewing the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets and it looks like this is already implemented, all you need to do is add this property to your MsBuild script:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SkipApp_DataFolder>True</SkipApp_DataFolder>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you are running from msbuild command line you can use:

`msbuild MyProject.csproj /p:SkipApp_DataFolder=True ...`

UPDATE:

You may want to try this, put this code at the bottom of your MsBuild file, after any "Import" tags:

```
  <Target Name="GenerateSkipRuleForAppData">
    <EscapeTextForRegularExpressions Text="$(_PackageTempDir)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="_Escaped_PackageTempDir" />
    </EscapeTextForRegularExpressions>
    <ItemGroup>
      <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipAddDataOnDeploy">
        <SkipAction></SkipAction>
        <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>$(_Escaped_PackageTempDir)\\App_Data$</AbsolutePath>
        <XPath></XPath>
      </MsDeploySkipRules>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

This is an exact copy of the "GenerateSkipRuleForAppData" target from Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets without a condition (seems like the condition is not working properly), this will overwrite the original target and should force it to be executed without break the logic of the targets.

Comment: No it's not working. The files are deleted from App_data on the application import in IIS.

Comment: I even found in the build output SkipApp_DataFolder = True