# VSTS Deployment does not execute package skip rules for Azure Web App deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops

## Question

We are currently deploying our MVC application using Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) to an Azure Web App and are facing issues with skip rules. We wanted to skip a folder during deployment `Content/Uploads` using a web deploy skip rule. However, it seems like VSTS is not executing that rule at all. The rules is packaged within the `deploy.cmd` file based on the following project configuration.

```
<PropertyGroup>
      <OnBeforePackageUsingManifest>AddCustomSkipRules</OnBeforePackageUsingManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="AddCustomSkipRules">
  <ItemGroup>
    <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipDeleteAppData">
      <SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>
      <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
      <AbsolutePath>\\Content\\Uploads</AbsolutePath>
      <XPath></XPath>
    </MsDeploySkipRules>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

This configuration add the following rule

```
-skip:skipaction='Delete',objectname='dirPath',absolutepath='\\Content\\Uploads'
```

Also, if I take this rule and copy it directly into the "Additional Argument" property of the VSTS aszure web app deployment step, it works like a charm.

I was wondering if I was missing something. I tried looking for other thread or example, without success. I've also try to change the `OnBeforePackageUsingManifest` for `AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest` as mentionned in comments from [Make MSDeploy (Visual Studio) not delete App_Data folder but delete everything else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289440/make-msdeploy-visual-studio-not-delete-app-data-folder-but-delete-everything-e) without success.

Thanks,

## Update

As of now, my guess is that the "Azure App Service Deploy" task from VSTS is not using the generated `cmd` file. It generates the command using the input parameter. Therefore I would need to add the skip rule manually within my deploy tasks instead of the project config.